# Overriding a base virtual property with a derived type is null when passing to JsonResult

Tags: c#

I have 2 base classes which 1 for search criteria and other 1 for search results.
I also have 2 derived classes for User object versions of both of those.

When I put a breakpoint in the controller action I can see all properties are populated as I've hardcoded.

When I call this action directly in the browser, each of my derived object properties is null.

I'm guessing the **JSON** serialization is not able to tell the difference from the base class to the derived one.

**Is there a way to solve this?**

```
public class BaseSearchCriteria
{
    public int Page { get; set; }
    public int RecordsPerPage { get; set; }
}

public class BaseSearchResults
{
    public int TotalResults { get; set; }
    public virtual BaseSearchCriteria SearchCriteria { get; set; }
}

public class UserSearchCriteria : BaseSearchCriteria
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
}

public class UserSearchResults : BaseSearchResults
{
    public new UserSearchCriteria SearchCriteria { get; set; }
}


public JsonResult Search(UserSearchCriteria model)
{
    var viewModel = new UserSearchResults
    {
        SearchCriteria = new UserSearchCriteria
        {
            Page = 1,
            RecordsPerPage = 15
        }
    };

    viewModel.TotalResults = 100;

    return Json(viewModel, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: avoid using hiding with `new`. generics would be the way to go with this.

Comment: @DanielA.White Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe good way to deal with it is to use generics as Daniel A. White propose.

Sample gist [here](https://gist.github.com/cloudikka/bb9465c653909f1e0dc7458436119b04).